# how to upload a file using jquery + c#

Tags: c#, jquery, forms

I'm having issues trying to upload a docx file. First, when I click on "Choose File", the prompt opens up but the page reloads going to CheckInController/CheckIn url ( I thought that what you add in the Html.BeginForm is where your controller and method go when you click on submit ). Second thing is how do I know that the contents of the document are being sent to the server and not just the name or id?

https://jsfiddle.net/w6adx6za/1/

```
<div class="session-filter">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckIn", "CheckInController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="select-filter-title"><strong>Select File</strong></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="fileResume" id="hiddenFileResume" type="file" value="" /><input type="submit" onclick="tested()"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>

function tested(){
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      url: "/SummaryStatementProcessing/CheckInSummaryStatement",
      data: data
  }); 
}

    public ActionResult CheckIn(HttpPostedFileBase fileResume){
         //work in here
    }
```

I don't need the page to go anywhere ( because this is actually in a dialog so it can close on submit, but currently it's reloading the page at the url above ). Currently I can't even get to the controller to check...

Comment: There is an error in the name of the controller, correct? You are calling CheckInSummaryStatement in the AJAX call and the Controller is called CheckIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require, the easiest method is to send a `FormData` object in the request. However, you should ideally be hooking to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` of the submit button, to stop the page redirecting.

You'll need to set the `processData` and `contentType` properties to `false` in the request. Also, the Action name does not appear to match your URL. You can fix that by using `@Url.Action`. The Action also needs the `[HttpPost]` attribute as that's the HTTP verb you're using in the AJAX request.

With all that said, try this:

```html
<div class="session-filter">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckIn", "CheckInController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
    <div class="select-filter-title"><strong>Select File</strong></div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="fileResume" id="hiddenFileResume" type="file" value="" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  }
</div>
```

```js
$('.session-filter form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckIn", "SummaryStatementProcessing")',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
  }); 
}
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckIn(HttpPostedFileBase fileResume)
{
  // work in here
}
```

With the above code in place, you should then be able to work with the `HttpPostedFileBase` class in the Action.

Comment: I've been watching at your edits and I thought I was making a lot of corrections to my posts! :).

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 lol, every time I edited I spotted something else which needed changing :)

Comment: I know, I feel the same way sometimes :) . I will also add that the controller needs the [HttpPost] as a decoration (just in case), your response seems complete now otherwise.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that one

Comment: i did have the decoration, just didnt add it, but thanks, ill look at this and see what i get

Comment: Great, sometimes you don't know what is on the other side and the more info the better.

Comment: hmm when I use submit instead of click, it doesnt do anything now. I can at least add in the file, but submitting it doesn't do anything

Comment: I just realised I missed a comma after the data property. Try my updated answer